# App store Application Submission Feedback

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store

I submitted my application to the App Store and I got that feedback,it is crashing on iPhone 3G running iPhone OS 3.0.1 and Mac OS X 10.5.8. I tested the application on the new SDK simulator 3.0 and replaced the deprecated methods. My question is, how to test the application on Mac OS X 10.5.8. ?

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Comment: I assume that you've tested the application on an actual device running 3.0.1, not just the simulator?  You can't always trust the simulator, particularly for something you're distributing.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you can'y test your iphone application on Mac OS X, otherwise it would be a Mac application.. or are you talking about the simulator? Like Brad said, its a simulator, not an emulator.

Comment: I submitted another question that has more information about this issue you can check it from the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358159/app-crash-on-iphone-3g-running-iphone-os-3-0-1-and-ipod-touch-running-iphone-os-3.

Comment: Sarah, for your information the App Store approval process feedback is protected by non-disclosure agreement (NDA). The rejection is not related to the simulator because a iPhone build (arm7 cpu) cannot be run in the simulator (i386 cpu). One year later, did you succeeded?

Comment: Thanks for the info, yes I was able to submit application successfully  few days later.