# app crash on iPhone 3G running iPhone OS 3.0.1 and iPod touch running iPhone OS 3.0 and Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store

My application was rejected because it is crashing on iPhone 3G running iPhone OS 3.0.1 and iPod touch running iPhone OS 3.0 and Mac OS X 10.5.8.   ,I thought that iPhone apps should be tested  only on iPhone . Why they test it on the mac?
I had some methods that was deprecated on SDK 3, and apple requires that the app should be build to the official SDK 2.2.1.  so I made pre-processor directives for the conditional compilation such as __IPHONE_3_0 and build two separate executables.I set the base SDK to the higher version iPhone 3 and the iPhone OS deployment target to the older version Iphone 2.2.1. I build the application from xcode without errors or warnings and it is lunched on the simulator. when I go to the build directory of the simulator release and try to run the application it fails. Is that what they meant that the app crashes on Mac OS X 10.5.8? I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.7 now. I need to resubmit the app as soon as possible. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Sarah

Comment: You should have edited your earlier identical question with this new information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356710/app-store-application-submission-feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice: ignore the Mac OS X 10.5.8 reference.  I just had an app get rejected (with the same notice), and after testing (and borrowing a friend's iPhone with OS 3.0.1) I was able to duplicate the problem.

(In other words, I think the key issue is that version of the OS on an iPhone -- the Mac reference is just the system they used for their internal tests)

Can you work around the deprecated items (i.e. rewrite the code so you don't have to rely on that functionality for older OSes)?  The reason I say that is, it's not like web browsers (where people don't upgrade).  Your users have no reason not to upgrade (and they'll be constantly prompted by Apple to update their devices)...

Comment: Doesn't the iPhone Touch upgrade from 2.x to 3.x cost $15, or something like that?  That would discourage some people from upgrading.  And some people will never upgrade, just because it scares them or because they automatically click "No" or "Cancel" whenever a dialog box appears asking a question.

Comment: True, but I don't think it's wise to hold yourself back forever simply based on those users.  Odds are, they won't be the ones buying your application anyway.